# Call-time pass-by-reference error, Unable to fix the code

Tags: php, arrays, function, error-handling, associative-array

Since I updated to php 5.4 i get the error  Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed, as i read, removing the `&` should solve it. It does, but now my code does not work anymore.

I need to make an Associative Array out of the string raw400, with the keys beeing t and f plus the number (example t410 and f410) and the value must be the value after the - without the -

Example:

```
t410-1:06,f410-15.4
```

schould become:

```
key: t410
value: 1:06

key: f410
value 15.4
```

The code..

```
$raw400 = 't410-1:06,f410-15.4,t390-1:06,f390-15.6,t370-1:05,f370-16.0,t350-1:05,f350-16.2,t330-1:04,f330-16.3,t310-1:00,f310-16.7';

$array = explode(',',$raw400);
$nm400 = array();
array_walk($array,'walk', $nm400);
function walk($val, $key, $nm400){
$nums = explode('-',$val);
$nm400[$nums[0]] = $nums[1];
}
```

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply make use of [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) for this trick.

```
<?php
$raw400 = 't410-1:06,f410-15.4,t390-1:06,f390-15.6,t370-1:05,f370-16.0,t350-1:05,f350-16.2,t330-1:04,f330-16.3,t310-1:00,f310-16.7';
parse_str(str_replace(array('-',','),array('=','&'),$raw400),$arr);
print_r($arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [t410] => 1:06
    [f410] => 15.4
    [t390] => 1:06
    [f390] => 15.6
    [t370] => 1:05
    [f370] => 16.0
    [t350] => 1:05
    [f350] => 16.2
    [t330] => 1:04
    [f330] => 16.3
    [t310] => 1:00
    [f310] => 16.7
)
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/115991)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`preg_match_all()`**](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all) and [**`array_combine`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
<?php
$raw400 = 't410-1:06,f410-15.4,t390-1:06,f390-15.6,t370-1:05,f370-16.0,t350-1:05,f350-16.2,t330-1:04,f330-16.3,t310-1:00,f310-16.7';
preg_match_all("/([^-, ]+)\,([^-,]+)/", $raw400, $res);
$array = array_combine($res[2], $res[1]);
print_r($array);
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Array
(
    [f410] => 1:06
    [t390] => 15.4
    [f390] => 1:06
    [t370] => 15.6
    [f370] => 1:05
    [t350] => 16.0
    [f350] => 1:05
    [t330] => 16.2
    [f330] => 1:04
    [t310] => 16.3
    [f310] => 1:00
)
```